# Spotfire date expression error

Tags: spotfire

In spotfire I have a column property fromDate and toDate which is a Date. I am trying to limit the result of data using expression below. But I keep on encountering this error

```
Invalid type for function call 'DocumentProperty' on line1, character 19
```

Limit Expression

```
[poddate] >= Date(DocumentProperty(${DevInfoYTD}.{Location}.{fromDate})) and 
[poddate] <= Date(DocumentProperty(${DevInfoYTD}.{Location}.{toDate}))
```

If I used the below expression i don't get an error but there is no data shown on the table.

```
[poddate] >= Date(${DevInfoYTD}.{Location}.{fromDate})
and [poddate] <= Date(${DevInfoYTD}.{Location}.{toDate})
```

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a three part identifier. I'm unsure of what that even is supposed to be, but you only need to list the property control.

```
[poddate] >= Date("${YourPropertyControlName}")
AND
and [poddate] <= Date("${YourOtherPropertyControlName}")
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I tried what you suggested on spotfire 7 and when I pressed ok it says fromDate is Undefined. Also if I double click the Property or click Insert Properties it gives me that three part identifier.

Comment: I've never seen the three part identifier, ever. However, put double quotes around the entire thing. Try that and let me know @dimas

Comment: Also, using DocumentProperty() is implied so it's not needed but doesn't hurt.

Comment: yup also tried enclosing it in double quotes and tried this Date(DocumentProperty("${DevInfoYTD}.{Location}.{fromDate}")) but it didn't work it will produce an error "The property '11/01/2016' does not exist

Comment: remove the DocumentProperty() part. @dimas

Comment: tried this [poddate] <= Date("${DevInfoYTD}.{Location}.{toDate}") no error, but it doesn't show any data....

Comment: And you are sure that there are results that would be <= that property control date? I can't reproduce your problem unfortunately.

Comment: yes i replaced the expression using hard-coded values and it gives some results [poddate] >= Date("2017/1/1") and [poddate] <= Date("2017/1/31")

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150098/discussion-between-scsimon-and-dimas).